# How to show posts as custom field in specific post type?

Tags: plugins

I have two post types called astronomy club and astro info. I need to link the astro info to astronnomy club which can be multiple select. In the backend how to create custom field with the list of astronomy club post and save into the database.

Example

```
Astronomy club: 
code: 9310

Astronomical info post type:
 email id firstname lastname
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  My cursory understanding is that you want to create an association between the two post types.  So IN the Astronomy Club post type you want to be able to associate multiple Astro Info posts?  Is that correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.